# get model with atleast one relation object in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I have a Person object which has_many companies. I would like to get the person with atleast one company. 
What I can get right now is

```
Person.where(:company_ids.size => 1)
```

This will return all the person with one company . But  I need something like

```
Person.where(:company_ids.size.gte => 1)
```

But it seems , this does not work.

Solution :

sorry for all the trouble, but found out that with previously created objects , I didn't have company_ids ... since I had only added that later. I can get the count with following :

```
Person.where(:company_ids.exists => true).and("this.company_ids.length > 0")
```

Thanks everyone for helping out.

Comment: is  company_ids a array field in person document?

Comment: yes company_ids is a array field . The solution provided below doesn't seem to work .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check doing as

`Person.where("this.company_ids >=1")`

Comment: this wont work, OP wants to get persons having at least one company. so you need to check the size

Answer (score 4):

I assume company_ids a array field in person document

I am afraid there is no way of specifying  conditions in size. But there is a workaround using javascript  $where expression

```
 db.person.find({$where: '(this.company_ids.length > 0)'})
```

am not sure about how to pass this expression in mongoid.

**EDIT**

yeah you can do this with mongoid too

```
Person.where("$where" =>  'this.company_ids.length >0;' )
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do:

`Person.where("this.company_ids.length > 3")`